# argument of type string is not assignable to type never

Tags: javascript, typescript, sinon

I have the following variable in file Test.ts

```
@state()
public controller? = new Editor(this);
```

In one of the functions handleAssetClick in Test.ts I call the function controller.closeEditor() which is an asynchronous function

```
await controller.closeEditor()
```

I am trying to write a test for Test.ts. How do I stub closeEditor so that I can write a unit test for handleAssetClick to test whether it calls dispatchEvent. Here's the code for handleAssetClick in Test.ts

```
private handleAssetClick() {
    await controller.closeEditor();
    this.dispatchEvent("event-name");
}
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example